# Ambiguous tag: [tag:separate]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

the tag [separate](/questions/tagged/separate) is used for several ambiguous things:

- Splitting a string (or an array)
- Indicating a text file format (e.g., comma separated)
- Segmenting an image
- etc.

It seems like tagging a question with [separate](/questions/tagged/separate) does not contribute any additional contextual information.

I suggest to remove this tag.

Edit:
is it possible for someone to automatically remove the tag from all questions, or should I do it myself?

Comment: Not sure I'm okay with the tag wiki edit, but otherwise, I agree.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi I say "Ni": feel free to edit the wiki.

Comment: Eh, I don't think it'll be around much longer anyway

Comment: I say kill it with fire! And beefy arms. But mostly fire.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I'm sorry if I offended you in any way. I think we are not on the same page here. No disrespect was intended.

Comment: @Shai wait, what? I wasn't offended in any way. In fact, I upvoted right after that. It was a reference to [peasant's quest](http://www.hrwiki.org/wiki/Peasant's_Quest), a game starring trogdor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This tag has been burninated <strike>[separate](/questions/tagged/separate)</strike> as it has no more questions associated with it. I removed the tag, edited questions and voted to close those which are off-topic with current standards.

The tag should disappear shortly..